# Get notification origin in windows 10 uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, notifications, windows-10

I'm writing a uwp app with notification listener and I'm trying to get the origin of a notification (like Google Chrome and the website it came from).

I tried using the AppInfo.DisplayInfo for a UserNotification but I can't get it to print the info, and I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this.

```
IReadOnlyList<UserNotification> notifs = await MainPage.listener.GetNotificationsAsync(Windows.UI.Notifications.NotificationKinds.Toast);
UserNotification n = notifs.Last();
var name = n.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;
```

I expected name to be the name of the app the notification came from but it seems to be empty or just not working. To be precise from a notification like this:
[image: notification example]

I want to extract the "Google Chrome" and / or "www.reddit.com".

Comment: Did you try looking at your `UserNotification` object through a debugger? You might be able to have a look at all its fields and see what info you can get and where to get it.

Comment: Yes I did and it seems like the only info available is the app it comes from (Google Chrome) and not the website. Well I guess I have to find a workaround if no one else knows how or if I can get the website it comes from.

Comment: hmm, you might have some chances with the `Visual` property of the notification which [contains the text (in bindings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notificationvisual) that might give you the information about the website.

Comment: No luck,it only contains the text from the notification (like the message from and the test parts) and no information where it came from.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. Never did something like this so I'm researching at the same time. Anyways, you might want to try the [push notification namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.pushnotifications) as this seems to be what web services are using.

Comment: Good idea, but it seems you can only get push notifications sent by your own app or by an app in the same package. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Have you refer this [docent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)?

Comment: Yes of course, but there seems to be no way to get the website the notification came from.

Comment: Your mean `Notification listener` can't detect the toast that comes from chrome?

Comment: No I mean the notification listener cannot extract the info from which website the notification came from. In my example I wanted to get "www.reddit.com" from the notification but that seems impossible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have found a solution by now, but in case this helps anyone:

The notification doesn't know that your message is coming from a browser. The whole Windows notifications system doesn't take that into an account. Windows receives a [UserNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.usernotification?view=winrt-19041) from an [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo?view=winrt-19041), which in your case happens to be a browser. So your "origin" is the application "Google Chrome". Your best shot is to try and get the link from inside the [notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notification?view=winrt-19041) itself, if it is inside the body somewhere.

I really think you should be able to find the link inside the text of the notification, but I would need more information on what exactly you are receiving to be sure. If you want to know how to read the text of the notification, do:

```
string appName = notif.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName; //this will get you "Google Chrome"
NotificationBinding toastBinding = notif.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);
 
if (toastBinding != null)
{
    IReadOnlyList<AdaptiveNotificationText> textElements = toastBinding.GetTextElements();
    string titleText = textElements.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;
    string bodyText = string.Join("\n", textElements.Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text));
    string website = ParseWebsiteFromText(bodyText); //my guess is the info you want is in here
}
```

From there you have to parse the information you want, if it's available.

If you want to know more, I suggest reading the documentation from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener.